# What is the right use of Data.Serialize "Either String"

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with Data.Serialize. When I encode a data structure then I can encode all data structures that are instances of the Serialize class. That works very well.

I then send it over the network.

However, I have a problem when decoding. The decoding function gives me back a type called "`Either String`" where I am not quite sure how to use this further to reconstruct my original data structure from that the recipient only knows that it had previously been an instance of `Serialize`.

```
receiveMessage :: Socket -> IO (a, SockAddr)
receiveMessage s  = do
        (msg, remoteSockAddr) <- recvFrom s 512
        return (S.decode $ msg, remoteSockAddr)

  Couldn't match type `a' with `Either String a0'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for receiveMessage :: Socket -> IO (a, SockAddr)
    In the expression: decode $ msg
    In the first argument of `return', namely
      `(decode $ msg, remoteSockAddr)'
    In the expression: return (decode $ msg, remoteSockAddr)
```

Using e.g.  `receiveMessage :: (Serialize a) => Socket -> IO (a, SockAddr)` is no help either. How could I deal with this and best get back my original data structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Either` is a type for handling errors. It is like `Maybe` except you can associate an arbitrary value (in this case some `String`) with the "error" case corresponding to `Maybe`'s `Nothing`.

That is, `Either String a` means that the result could either be a `String` or the data you want to deserialize.

You can get your data out of the `Either` by pattern matching. `Either` has two constructors: `Left` and `Right`. In this case, `Left` will have some string and `Right` will have your value. So you would do something like this:

```
case S.decode msg of
  Left str  -> ... -- handle your data not being deserialized correctly here
  Right res -> ... -- res is your data
```

Also, you will have to specify that the result is some serializable type. Right now, your `receiveMessage` function promises to return *any* type `a`; instead, you can only return a type from the `Serialize` class. So change the type signature to something like `Serialize a => Socket -> IO (a, SockAddr)`.

When you actually use your function, `Haskell` will know what type `a` is supposed to be and will choose the appropriate deserialization code. However, since this code only exists for instances of the `Serialize` typeclass, you have to specify that in the type signature.

On an unrelated note: you do not need the `$` operator in `S.decode $ msg`. You can think of the operator as adding parens surrounding what follows it, so the `S.decode $ msg` line is equivalent to `S.decode (msg)`, which is unnecessary and could be left as `S.decode msg`.

Comment: Thanks, thought the parens in this case are around (msg, remoteSockAddr), at least it behaves as if ... .

Comment: Those parens are different and just there to make a tuple. The `$` would only extend to the `,` in this case, so `(S.decode $ msg, remoteSockAddr)` is the same as `(S.decode (msg), remoteSockAddr)` which is still redundant.